# Create method to count occurrences of type char within an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a method that searches a String array whether a specfic character exists in the array and returns an integer of the number of occurrences the character appears, I have looked on other posts to try and work it out myself but they are all arrays of int not String

I have another class name hence the array name being type Name.

```
public class Reg {

    //Fields
    private ArrayList<Name> Name; 


    //Constructors
    public Reg() {
        Name = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //Methods

    public int CountCharacterOccurrences (Char character){

    }
}
```

Name Class:

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {

    //Fields
    private String firstName;
    private String familyName;


    //Constructors
    public Name() {
        firstName = "";
        familyName = "";
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String familyName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }


    //Methods
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        if (firstName.equals("") && familyName.equals("")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return firstName + " " + familyName;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name:[firstName=" + firstName + ", familyName=" + familyName + "]";
    }
}
```

How do I add a method CountCharacterOccurences that accepts a char argument and returns an int signalling the number of occurrences.

Comment: for starters you should return a type `int` since you want the count , right?

Comment: Will you want to search a char in String array?

Comment: Where is the array that you need to search through? I believe you also should be passing the array in the function that you need to search through. The method signature should look something like `public int countFirstNameOccurrences(char c, String[] strArray)`.

Comment: @clinomaniac The array is declared in the class, I'm trying to add a method that accepts a char argument and returns an int signalling the number of occurrences of a specific character.

Comment: Is it a String array? Can you show what its called? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: What is this class `Name`???

Comment: Your question is unclear right now. Please add the class `Name` and explain exactly what you want.

Comment: @EbraheemAlrabee' See Edit

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza See latest edit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you mean:

```
class Reg{
    private ArrayList<Name> names;

    public Reg() {
        names = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int countFirstNameOccurrences(char c) {
        return names.stream()            // get Stream<Name>
                .map(Name::getFirstName) // convert Stream<Name> to Stream<String> using Name's firstName
                .mapToInt(s -> s.length() - s.replace(String.valueOf(c), "").length()) // calculate every occurrence c in each firstName and get an IntStream
                .sum();                  // sum all the values
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reg reg = new Reg();
        reg.names.add(new Name("John", "Doe"));
        reg.names.add(new Name("Johnny ", "Doe"));
        reg.names.add(new Name("Richard", "Roe"));
        reg.names.add(new Name("James", "Roe"));
        reg.names.add(new Name("Jane", "Roe"));

        System.out.println(reg.countFirstNameOccurrences('J'));
    }
}
```

Output:

> 4

as there are 4 J's in the first names in the list (John, Johnny, James and Jane)

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what i needed Thank you!

Comment: How could edit the stream so it just counts the first names last letter of each string, so for your example the output for all letters would be 1

Comment: Now that's a different question which I suggest you to ask in a new post.